# In which thread is TIdThreadComponent OnTerminate and OnStopped executed?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy, indy10

Really simple but important question concerning `TIdThreadComponent`:

In which thread are `OnTerminate` and `OnStopped` executed - main thread or the worker thread?

Can I safely assume I am in main thread when I am in these events (and call VCL properties and methods)?

**Update:** I figured I might use debugger and after trying that, looks like `OnStopped` is within worker thread and `OnTerminate` is inside main thread. Additional benefit is that debugger can help with determining where other related functions for starting/stopping/controlling thread are executed and reduce possible bugs.

Comment: You can always determine the current ThreadContext with GetCurrentThreadID and compare it with MainThreadID :o)

Comment: Yes, I did that later as well. Useful advice though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your observation is correct.  `OnStopped` is triggered in the context of the worker thread.  `OnTerminated` is triggered in the context of the main thread.